# batch file stop wait 3 min. and restart .exe if finds this error message?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have this script who works fine:

> This is output.txt path--> C:\Windows\windefender\output.txt

,so when finds the word

> ''error #10054 (Unknown error)'' inside Output.txt then the
>   ''mskscss'' process is stopped.

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set FNLog=C:\Windows\windefender\output.txt
if exist "%FNLog%" (
  find " error #10054 (Unknown error)" "%FNLog%"
  if !errorlevel! equ 0 NET STOP "mskscss (managed by AlwaysUpService)"
  ECHO del /q "%FNLog%"
)
```

Now can anyone help me add this?So after ''mskscss'' process is stopped, wait 3 minutes and then restart my service,with a new command something like this: net start mskscss ...etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### After ''mskscss'' process is stopped, wait 3 minutes and then restart my service

You can use the following commands:

```
timeout /t 120 /nobreak
net start "mskscss (managed by AlwaysUpService)"
```

Modified batch file:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set FNLog=C:\Windows\windefender\output.txt
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
  call :sub
  NET STOP "mskscss (managed by AlwaysUpService)"
  goto :eof
  )

:sub
  if exist "%FNLog%" (
    find " error #10054 (Unknown error)" "%FNLog%"
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
      NET STOP "mskscss (managed by AlwaysUpService)"
      timeout /t 120 /nobreak
      net start "mskscss (managed by AlwaysUpService)
      goto :done
      )
    find "--- rate 0.00'" "%FNLog%"
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
      NET STOP "mskscss (managed by AlwaysUpService)"
      timeout /t 120 /nobreak
      net start "mskscss (managed by AlwaysUpService)
      goto :done
      )
  :done
    del /q "%FNLog%"
  )
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - Conditionally perform a command several times.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.
- [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) - Delay execution for a few seconds or minutes, for use within a batch file.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60451/discussion-on-answer-by-davidpostill-batch-file-stop-wait-3-min-and-restart-ex).